# apostrophe, compound noun, compound modifier

Tags: punctuation, possessives

I was trying to decide whether to put an apostrophe at the end of "couples" in this sentence:

> *You're invited to the annual married couples breakfast.*

My knee-jerk answer is yes, it needs an apostrophe. But then I got to thinking about contrary examples, similarly structured. I wouldn't, for instance, put an apostrophe after "clothes" in this example:

> *Your coat is upstairs in the winter clothes closet.*

My overall question: Why does the first example seem to work well with that apostrophe (though I can see it going either way) while the second seems absolutely correct without it? I can't work out the structural difference between the two examples.

Comment: I would say that 'clothes' is a generic term for 'wearing apparel' rather than a plural noun as such.

Comment: @KateBunting: To use different examples, "book shelf" or "tool shed" are common, the plural generally isn't except for pluralisms like "parents". Arguably, "couples" could be understood as a pluralism within the compound noun, because "a wedding couple dance" would be a different thing. The tendency to use the possessive "'s" is separate from the plural s, german has the Fugen-S, but different plural forms, however the Fugen-S is not always used (Paartanz vs Paarestanz) and likewise not needed in English, because English is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they would both be correct with apostrophes at the end of couples and clothes. The reason you would definitely want to say *couples' dance*, and probably not say *clothes closet*, is because the latter is a common enough phrase that it has become a compound noun in popular usage. *Couples dance* is not as common a phrase, and therefore sounds more awkward if you make it a compound noun rather than a possessive followed by a noun.